# Excel VBA Selenium click second button

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

I am trying to program in Excel VBA with selenium to click on a button but the web (http://app.bde.es/rss_www/) has two buttons with the same "Type" and "Class".

```
<input type="button" class="boton" value="Consultar en PDF" onclick="irAConsulta(document.getElementById('entidad').value, document.getElementById('objetivo').value, document.getElementById('paisRegistro').value, document.getElementById('sector').value, document.getElementById('ejercicio').value, document.getElementById('dimension').value, document.getElementById('pais').value, '0');">

<input type="button" class="boton" value="Consultar en EXCEL" onclick="irAConsultaExcel(document.getElementById('entidad').value, document.getElementById('objetivo').value, document.getElementById('paisRegistro').value, document.getElementById('sector').value, document.getElementById('ejercicio').value, document.getElementById('dimension').value, document.getElementById('pais').value, '0');">
```

I need to click on the second one to download the data in Excel.

If I type :

```
OBJ.FindElementByClass("button").Click
```

This Clicks on the first one (the PDF), how can I click on the second one for the excel data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`FindElementBy*` will always return the first matching element. So the [*locator strategy*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48376890/7429447) you have used always returned the first matching element, which is the control for downloading the data in *PDF* format.

To identify the element for downloading the data in *Excel* format you need to identify the [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52805139/7429447) uniquely and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *FindElementByCss* and *onclick* attribute:

  ```
  OBJ.FindElementByCss("input[onclick^='irAConsultaExcel']").Click
  ```
- Using *FindElementByCss* and *value* attribute:

  ```
  OBJ.FindElementByCss("input[value='Consultar en EXCEL']").Click
  ```
- Using *FindElementByXPath* and *onclick* attribute:

  ```
  OBJ.FindElementByXPath("//input[starts-with(@onclick, 'irAConsultaExcel')]").Click
  ```
- Using *FindElementByXPath* and *value* attribute:

  ```
  OBJ.FindElementByXPath("//input[@value='Consultar en EXCEL']").Click
  ```

Answer (score 2):

You can locate that element with XPath or CSS Selector.
By XPath:

```vb
OBJ.FindElementByXPath("//input[@value='Consultar en EXCEL']").Click
```

By CSS Selector:

```vb
OBJ.findElementByCssSelector("input[value='Consultar en EXCEL']").Click
```